# Get-AzureStorageShare is missing?

Tags: powershell, azure, module, share

Did I just forgot to import some modules or something else?

Information: Get-AzureStorageContainer Version: 4.0.2

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a moment to read this: "How to ask questions on StackOverflow" stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-azurestorageshare is only avaible in the following powershell modules.Please download the latest powershell module and retry the operation.

[image]